# Pytest E ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pruebas'

Tags: python, selenium

soy nuevo en Pytest y estoy teniendo problemas para importar una función desde otro archivo.

```
/Test1
 /pruebas
  /reusables.py
  /test_01.py
```

En reusables.py solamente está una función sleep

```
import time

def sleep3():
    time.sleep(3)
```

En tesT_01.py está así:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pruebas import reusables

def test_setup():
    # Abrir Chrome
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Desktop/segmentos_tct/chromedriver_81.exe")

    # Maximizar Ventana
    driver.maximize_window()

    # Esperar 5 segundos para que cargue la página
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    # Obtener URL
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
    reusables.sleep3()

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Al ejecutar el archivo pytest en la terminal obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

```
========================================================================================== ERRORS 

    ==========================================================================================
_______________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_01.py ________________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Test1\pruebas\test_01.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test_01.py:2: in <module>
    from pruebas import reusables
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pruebas'
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso al estar en la misma carpeta el script de ejecución con el que quieres importar, simplemente puedes importar el fichero. Así te debería funcionar:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from reusables import sleep3

def test_setup():
    # Abrir Chrome
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Desktop/segmentos_tct/chromedriver_81.exe")

    # Maximizar Ventana
    driver.maximize_window()

    # Esperar 5 segundos para que cargue la página
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    # Obtener URL
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
    sleep3()

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```